# In Google Apps Script, how to send an email only one time if condition met

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, triggers, google-sheets

I'm trying to make automatic email send when a certain cell has required value. I figured out how to do this continually, i.e. a trigger is set to fire each day at a certain time of day to check the condition and send email if it's met. But I'd like the trigger to stop working after email was sent once. I thought I could do it this way:

I have a function which sends an email if condition is met. If condition is not met, a trigger is created, which will run the function again, once. And so on, trigger will continue to be created until once a condition is met.

Here is a code I wrote:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var ssName = ss.getName();
var emailAddress = ss.getRange("Tab1!B4").getValue();
var Test1 = ss.getRange("Tab1!B6").getValue();

function SendEmailOnce(){
  if (Test1 <= 10) {
    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: emailAddress,
      subject: "Sample subject: " + ssName,
      htmlBody: "Sample message<br/> Regards, robot",
    });
    }
    else {
      function createTriggerCheckAgain() {
      ScriptApp.newTrigger('SendEmailOnce')
      .timeBased()
      .after(60 * 1000)
      .create();
      }
    }
}
```

For some reason it doesn't work. When I run the function while Test1 value being 15, and then change the value to 5, no email is sent.

The parts of it work if they are separate: 
1. The email is sent if the value is 5 when I run the function.
2. The email is sent after a minute after I run the function of creating that trigger while value is 5.

Maybe there is a simpler way to do this? I'm a newbie in JavaScript. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

When your trigger runs after 60 seconds, `Test1` is no longer defined, so you cannot check if `undefined` is `<= 10`. The reason for this is because only the code in `SendEmailOnce` is executed, not the code outside of it. The same also goes for the `emailAddress` variable.

You either need to include your first four lines of code in a function that you can call, which returns the value of `Test1` and `emailAddress` or include it in your `SendEmailOnce` function.

Modified Code:

```
function SendEmailOnce(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ssName = ss.getName();
  var emailAddress = ss.getRange("Tab1!B4").getValue();
  var Test1 = ss.getRange("Tab1!B6").getValue();

  if (Test1 <= 10) {
    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: emailAddress,
      subject: "Sample subject: " + ssName,
      htmlBody: "Sample message<br/> Regards, robot",
    });
  }
  else {
    function createTriggerCheckAgain() {
      ScriptApp.newTrigger('SendEmailOnce')
      .timeBased()
      .after(60 * 1000)
      .create();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It didn't work, but probably because of some other stuff which I was missing. But I was able to make it all work in a different way: I just schedule a trigger, which when condition is met, sends the email, and then deletes the original trigger. Still, thanks a lot for your effort!